# Python scrape with Selenium and Beautifulsoup extracting hyperlink only href no link

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape NBA player with their hyperlink URL, but no matter what I tried, result in only href name and number, any way to extract URL from the hyperlink, Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOTL3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qncjg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The href links on the page are relative links. When you pull out those links, store them in a list, then iterate through the links and prepend the url of the webpage to those links.

`https://stats.nba.com/player/1628960/` url gives you the info of a certain player, but you only have `/player/1628960/` in your href lists. That means you need to prepend `https://stats.nba.com` to every entry in the list.

You can try the following

```
url = 'https://stats.nba.com'
new_links = []
for link in player list:
    new_links.append(url + link)
```

Or you can prepend the url at the time of scraping those links.